# WordPress post meta nesting arrays instead of adding to array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am struggling with something that I thought would be simple. Retrieve a post meta array, search it and add to it. The search never finds a user if they have been added and from what I can see the meta key value ends up being an increasingly nested multidimensional array.

```
// Get post ID
$id = get_the_ID();

// Get array of signed up users
$users_signed_up = get_post_meta($id, 'users_signed_up', false);

// Get the user ID
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Search retrieved array
if (!in_array($user_id, $users_signed_up)) {

    // Add user to array
    array_push($users_signed_up, $user_id);

    // Add array back to post meta
    update_post_meta($id, 'users_signed_up', $users_signed_up);
}
```

var_dump of users_signed_up with a couple of users added by avoiding the in_array search.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(32) } [1]=> int(36) } [1]=> int(1) } }
```

However what I expect it to look like is this.

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(32) [2]=> int(36) }
```

Comment: you should always use 'true' when getting post meta (get_post_meta($id, 'users_signed_up', true); ). The codex is confusing with that, but even if youre meta value is an array you should 'true'. It will return the array you need. I believe that may be the root of your problem.

Comment: If you're willing to venture outside of the standard wordpress infrastructure it might be worthwhile to make a MySQL table to store all of your users. From experience, of having done it with post meta and a MySQL table, the mysql table will be a nicer solution in the long run.

Comment: You are correct, I needed to use true. My mistake was thinking that true would only ever return a string and that using false would allow me to store an array. I've spent a while using WordPress now and I'm not sure how I made it this far without realising this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$users_signed_up = get_post_meta($id, 'users_signed_up', true);

if (!in_array($user_id, $users_signed_up)) {

    // Add user to array
    $users_signed_up[]= $user_id;

    // Add array back to post meta
    update_post_meta($id, 'users_signed_up', $users_signed_up);
}
```

should do it assuming the original array is correct

Comment: This gives the same result of nested arrays.

Comment: then its the array stored in get post meta.i updated your get post meta to use true instead of false....if you are returning a array of arrays (which wouldn't really be correct for this use) you need to combine them....